# Co-occurrence statistics for sets

Tags: correlation, clustering, multivariate-analysis, combinatorics

I am looking for help in the following situation:

I have a set of numbers $A=\{1, 2, \dots, 100\}$, and I am drawing subsets of 10 of these numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{10}\}$ according to an underlying distribution that I do not know. After doing this procedure $N$ times (which can be very large), I would like to know if certain subsets of $A$ (of 9 or fewer numbers) are drawn as part of a single larger subset of 10 more often than would be expected by chance.

Essentially, I am trying to find subsets of $A$ the co-occur together more often than would be expected by chance when A is sampled in sets of 10.

Are there any well established statistics for this sort of thing?

Comment: Will plain hierarchical clustering do? Create size 100 square symmetric matrix of co-occurence frequency. Cluster by, say, complete linkage. Observe the dendrogram and cut the branches at most persuasive levels.